# Spring R2DBC - Getting "Table already exists" error while creating h2 table using schema.sql and ConnectionFactoryInitializer

Tags: h2, spring-data-r2dbc

Getting the error "Table Customer already exists" when i tried to create a table in H2 in memory database using schema.sql. I am using spring boot version: 2.5.4 and below is my pom.xml. It works fine if i use spring boot version: 2.4.3

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.4</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.sample</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>r2dbc-h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Here is my code:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Customer {
  @Id
  String id;
  String name;
}


//schema.sql
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(255));

@SpringBootApplication
public class ReactivedemoApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ReactivedemoApplication.class, args);
  }

  @Bean
  ConnectionFactoryInitializer initializer(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {

        ConnectionFactoryInitializer initializer = new ConnectionFactoryInitializer();
        initializer.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        initializer.setDatabasePopulator(new ResourceDatabasePopulator(new 
        ClassPathResource("schema.sql")));
        return initializer;
   }
}
```

When i start the app, i am getting the below error. How to force H2 to create the table using schema.sql ?

Caused by: io.r2dbc.spi.R2dbcBadGrammarException: Table "CUSTOMER" already exists; SQL
statement:
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(255)) [42101-200]
at io.r2dbc.h2.H2DatabaseExceptionFactory.convert(H2DatabaseExceptionFactory.java:81) ~[r2dbc-h2-0.8.4.RELEASE.jar:0.8.4.RELEASE]
at io.r2dbc.h2.H2Statement.lambda$execute$2(H2Statement.java:155) ~[r2dbc-h2-0.8.4.RELEASE.jar:0.8.4.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:113) ~[reactor-core-3.4.9.jar:3.4.9]
... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "CUSTOMER" already exists; SQL
statement:
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(255)) [42101-200]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As spring already created the table from the root location schema.sql, ConnectionFactoryInitializer bean is not needed. Removing the ConnectionFactoryInitializer bean declaration fixed the issue.

Comment: Removing my custom ConnectionFactoryInitializer Bean worked for me. 
Using H2 on Spring Boot 2.6.4, Java 11 and  spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc.